# Can't create a text input in Blackberry apps

Tags: apache-flex, blackberry-playbook, flex4.6

I keep getting an error when I try to run an app on BB Playbook that says `Cannot create property editable on qnx.fuse.ui.text.StageTextInput`.  The same exact code works fine in Android and on the Flash Builder built in simulator, but errors on a physical Playbook and in the Blackberry Playbook Simulator. The area of code that seems to be causing the error is as follows:

```
<s:VGroup includeIn="login" top="10" left="10" right="10" id="loginForm">
    <s:Label text="Email" />
    <s:TextInput id="txt_email" width="100%" softKeyboardType="email" />
    <s:Label text="Password" />
    <s:TextInput id="txt_password" width="100%" displayAsPassword="true" />
    <s:Button id="btn_login" label="Login" click="authenticate()" fontWeight="normal"/>
</s:VGroup>
```

And the stacktrace:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property editable on qnx.fuse.ui.text.StageTextInput.
    at flash.text::StageText/init()
    at flash.text::StageText()
    at StageTextPool$/acquireStageText()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\mobilecomponents\src\spark\components\supportClasses\StyleableStageText.as:3072]
    at spark.components.supportClasses::StyleableStageText/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::getStageText()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\mobilecomponents\src\spark\components\supportClasses\StyleableStageText.as:2415]
    at spark.components.supportClasses::StyleableStageText()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\mobilecomponents\src\spark\components\supportClasses\StyleableStageText.as:403]
    at spark.skins.mobile.supportClasses::StageTextSkinBase/createChildren()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\mobiletheme\src\spark\skins\mobile\supportClasses\StageTextSkinBase.as:185]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/initialize()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:7634]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::childAdded()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:7495]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/addChild()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:7176]
    at spark.components.supportClasses::SkinnableComponent/attachSkin()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\supportClasses\SkinnableComponent.as:692]
    at spark.components.supportClasses::SkinnableComponent/validateSkinChange()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\supportClasses\SkinnableComponent.as:443]
    at spark.components.supportClasses::SkinnableComponent/createChildren()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\supportClasses\SkinnableComponent.as:406]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/initialize()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:7634]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::childAdded()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:7495]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/addChildAt()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:7199]
    at spark.components::Group/addDisplayObjectToDisplayList()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Group.as:2037]
    at spark.components::Group/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::elementAdded()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Group.as:1628]
    at spark.components::Group/setMXMLContent()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Group.as:633]
    at spark.components::Group/createChildren()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Group.as:855]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/initialize()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:7634]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::childAdded()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:7495]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/addChildAt()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:7199]
    at spark.components::Group/addDisplayObjectToDisplayList()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Group.as:2037]
    at spark.components::Group/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::elementAdded()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Group.as:1628]
    at spark.components::Group/addElementAt()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Group.as:1387]
    at spark.components::SkinnableContainer/addElementAt()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\SkinnableContainer.as:775]
    at mx.states::AddItems/addItemsToContentHolder()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\states\AddItems.as:782]
    at mx.states::AddItems/apply()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\states\AddItems.as:563]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/applyState()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:10741]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/commitCurrentState()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:10487]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/commitProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8304]
    at spark.components.supportClasses::SkinnableComponent/commitProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\supportClasses\SkinnableComponent.as:452]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8219]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:597]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:813]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1180]
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Comment: Which version of Flex are you using? I don't think Playbook supports the latest version of Flex/AIR yet.  IF you're using Flex 4.6 I think the default TextInput skin uses a native text control (StageText) not the "Default" Flex control (TextField).  [This was not the case in 4.5]

Comment: I am on Flex 4.6.  Should I downgrade to 4.5 or is there a way to have it use the Flex control instead of the native control?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Best info I can find is that Playbook doesn't support AIR 3 yet ( http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Tablet-OS-SDK-for-Adobe-AIR/Tips-Definitive-guide-to-AIR-apps-for-playbook/td-p/1080047 ).  IF so, you'll have to downgrade, or possibly Captive Runtime will work.  The "old skin" should still be there, so you could specify the skinclass to 'spark.skins.mobile.TextAreaSkin'

Answer (score 0):

PlayBook qnx.fuse components cannot be used in Flex.

About Flex AIR version, I believe PlayBook actually supports Flex 4.6 and AIR 3 on PlayBookOS 1.0.8 and 2.0.0

Comment: I have been testing on OS 1.0.8 and the AIR version is 3.1.0.20, but I get the error that I posted above.